Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\sqrt{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ on $(0,1)$
I want to check whether this series of functions converges uniformly or not.
$\textit{Attempt:}$ I have used Weierstrass M-Test to find the maximal value for $f_n(x)$ and I got $M_n=(\frac{2n}{2n+1})^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n$ does not converge, so this method didn't work.
[Let $f_n'(x)=nx^{n-1}\sqrt{1-x} \ +x^n\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{1-x}}=0$, we find that $x_a=\frac{2n}{2n+1} $, thus its maximal value is $f_n(x_a)$]
Then, I tried to prove that it was not true by showing a contradiction of $|\sum_{n\geq N } x^n\sqrt{1-x}|<\epsilon, \forall \epsilon>0$, but I did not approach it. Any hints? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Do you know what it converges to?

@BrianMoehring  $\frac{x\sqrt{1-x}}{1-x}$

Your series is not uniformly convergent in $(0,1)$.
$$S_n(x)=\frac{x(1-x^{n})\sqrt{1-x}}{1-x}\to f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}.$$
$$|S_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1-x}}\to\infty,\quad x\to1.$$
Another method: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\sqrt{1-x}$ is uniformly convergent in $(0,1)$, it must be uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.
So $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ would be continuous on $[0,1]$,
which is not ture at $x=1$!

could you give more detailed information? like the method or some hints

Thank you! I am also from China, haha.

Shake hand! Your location shows you are in Liverpool.

Study abroad. And nice to meet you.

Cool, nice to meet you too!

Why should $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ if it is continuous on $(0,1)$, i.e., why is there a continuous extension? @Riemann

@ stoic-santiago
If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\sqrt{1-x}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$, with $f_n(x)=x^n\sqrt{1-x}$ continuous on $[0,1]$, then the sum function $f$ would be continuous on $[0,1]$.

@Riemann I think the confusion part is this claim: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $(a,b),$ then it is uniformly convergent on $[a,b].$

It is just Cauchy's  test：$$|f_{n+1}(x)+\cdots+f_{n+p}(x)|<\epsilon,\forall x\in(0,1),$$ let $x\to0$ , we can get $$|f_{n+1}(0)+\cdots+f_{n+p}(0)|\leq\epsilon.$$  The same for $x=1$.

@Riemann Nicely seen, thank you again!
